# Customize Google auth action domain in nextjs

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have completed the verification process of my domain and updated my authdomain in config. Only now when I try google signin the url return a 404 since my nextjs app is supposed to handle 404s for unknown pages.
This is the url it redirects to in popup, mydomain.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=AIz****. How do I accommodate for this in NextJs

Comment: Which version of NextJS are you using? If 13+, are you using appdir?

Comment: No using version 12

Comment: @Taio did you get to find a solution to this?

Comment: Create a folder named __auth and add a page called action.js inside

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this was my solution. In my `next.config.mjs`, I added this:

```js
rewrites: function () {
    return [
      {
        source: "/__/auth/:path*",
        destination: `<MY_ORIGINAL_FIREBASE_PROJECT_AUTH_DOMAIN>/__/auth/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
```

From my understanding, adding the `/__/auth/handler` to the end of your domain only works for projects hosted by firebase itself. For other projects (in my example, I am hosting on vercel) this is just seen as some route that next will look for in the app/ or pages/ directory, hence the 404. The rewrite in the `next.config.mjs` tells next to proxy the request to `<my-domain>/__/auth/*` to instead go to `<my_original_firebase_auth_domain>/__/auth/*`.

By original firebase auth domain, I mean the one that looks like the firebase-app-name-123.firebaseapp.com

Make sure to do steps 3 and 4 in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#expandable-4) before doing this so that the popup window still shows your custom domain.